# Firebase not working com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException

Tags: android, firebase

I am working on an Android app, I was in a situation that I want to move the app to a new firebase project, so I removed the old firebase project and created a new one, then I added my app to that project. After that, no firebase functionalities are working.

I have firebase cloud messaging in my app, it was working but it's not working now, I am not receiving `FirebaseMessagingService$onNewToken`and also I am using `firestore` as my back-end database. Inside my `.addOnSuccessListener` I am getting `0` documents back. It's not failing but returning no documents.

I thought might be a problem with firebase, so I created a test app in `node.js` and I try to fetch documents from `firestore` it's working fine.

The android app is not crashing, but checked the error log, and I am seeing the following log.

```java
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzb(Unknown Source:61)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:23)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.1:54)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.1:89)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzv.run(Unknown Source:12)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doRegistrationInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-installations@@16.0.0:333)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doGetId(com.google.firebase:firebase-installations@@16.0.0:280)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.access$lambda$0(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2020-03-05 21:18:49.022 23658-23666/app.spidy.cyberwire E/spidy.cyberwir: Something went wrong getting fds from adb. Retry!: Success
2020-03-05 21:20:11.198 23658-24183/app.spidy.cyberwire E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzb(Unknown Source:61)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:23)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.1:54)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.1:89)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzv.run(Unknown Source:12)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doRegistrationInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-installations@@16.0.0:333)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doGetId(com.google.firebase:firebase-installations@@16.0.0:280)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.access$lambda$0(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2020-03-05 21:22:41.287 23658-24278/app.spidy.cyberwire E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzb(Unknown Source:61)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:23)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.1:54)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.1:89)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzv.run(Unknown Source:12)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doRegistrationInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-installations@@16.0.0:333)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doGetId(com.google.firebase:firebase-installations@@16.0.0:280)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.access$lambda$0(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2020-03-05 21:27:11.330 23658-24399/app.spidy.cyberwire E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzb(Unknown Source:61)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:23)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.1:54)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.1:89)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzv.run(Unknown Source:12)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doRegistrationInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-installations@@16.0.0:333)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doGetId(com.google.firebase:firebase-installations@@16.0.0:280)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.access$lambda$0(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:2)
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

If you have recently change your `google-services.json` file then just delete `build` folder from android project and re-build your project.

Comment: What happened to me is that on the Google Cloud Console, in the Credentials section, some API keys were restricted to Android apps, and some of the hashes that were registered didn't exist anymore. I removed them and I stopped getting that error.

Comment: That was the solution for me after creating a new flavor, i had to add a new google-service.json file. After deleting the build folders, it worked fine

Answer (score 48):

I had the same problem because access to internet (wifi and mobile) was disabled

Comment: If your emulator is showing limited connection on wifi, use mobile data on it. That solved the problem for me.

Comment: I had a problem like this. I have used starbucks wifi and it does not allow the internet for simulator. Then i change my wifi , problem solved.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem (Failed to get FIS auth token) with `firebase-messaging` version `20.1.1` and `20.1.2`. I've solved it by downgrading to `20.1.0`.

It looks like Firebase team has some problems with these versions according to [Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions): 
`Warning: The following two library versions released with this update have known issues and should not be used: firebase-messaging v20.1.1 and firebase-iid v20.1.0.`

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Not very many search results for this error. Thought it was a misconfig. Downgrading resolved.

Answer (score 12):

Firebase Android SDK [updates on February 27](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2020-02-27) (M65) and afterwards introduced a new infrastructure service, the Firebase Installations SDK which comes with a dependency on the [Firebase Installations API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com). 
Firebase Installations requires valid Firebase options `API key`, `project ID`, and `application ID` (a.k.a. "`appId`") in order to successfully communicate with Firebase servers.

Errors during communication with the Firebase Installations API indicate invalid Firebase options or misconfigurations regarding API keys.

To mitigate the issue

- make sure that your application is using valid Firebase options from the latest `google-services.json` file from your Firebase console:
  [Firebase options: instructions and background](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-installations/REQUIRED_FIREBASE_OPTIONS_ANDROID.md).
- If you use API restrictions, make sure that the API key used by your application is white-listed for the Firebase Installations API (and for your application):
  [API restrictions: instructions and background](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-installations/API_KEY_RESTRICTIONS.md)
- Regarding `Application restrictions`: Either set the radio button to `None` or make sure that your app is white-listed (with the correct `SHA-1 certificate`).

---

For details, please visit: 
https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy/init-options

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and in my case, my android emulator didn't have Google Play Services added. Created a new one with Google Play Services services and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

There could be multiple reasons for the above error. The one which I have faced is due to **SHA-1 certificate fingerprint** restrictions.
Was facing the above issue for the **Android** in the **store build** due to restrictions.

**Steps to avoid this error.**

- Add your SHA-1 certificate fingerprint to the firebase project setup
- Also add the same SHA-1 certificate fingerprint in Google Cloud Console.

**Steps to add SHA-1 certificate fingerprint to Google Cloud Console:**

- Open Google Cloud Console & Select your project
- Click API`s & Services Tab
- Then Select Creditionals
- Then go API Section
- And Finally, check your SHA-1 Key is added on Restrict usage to your Android apps section or not. If not add it with the package name and SHA-1 Key.

Comment: How does one identify the cause of the error is due to SHA-1 firngerprint restrictions ?

Comment: This worked for me. Strangely, adding a Sha1 fingerprint to the Firebase console didn't automatically add it to the Cloud Console.

Comment: i struck here for 3 days and almost answer in everypost mention about firebase project only. thanks !

Comment: Adding the SHA-1 to Google Cloud Console fixed for me, thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Solution 1

1. If you made any configuration changes in the firebase console - Redownload and update `google-services.json` file in the project.

> Solution 2

1. If You are using a `Real device` Check your Internet connection.
2. If you are using android studio `Emulator` - Establish an internet connection by resetting the emulator.

   2.1. Open `Tools -> AVD manager`

[image: Step 2.1]

2.2. Wipe Data of the emulator
[image: Wipe Data of the emulator 2.2]

3. Run Project using fresh emulator.

Comment: Checking Internet connection for Real device worked for me

Comment: Same, checking the internet connection worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

just delete the google-services.json file form the project ,clean project, after that rebuild the project

Comment: Yeah, and if u make some changes in Firebase console, redownload google-services.json and put new after clean and rebuild, that make help too
And double check package id

Answer (score 2):

Instead of downgrading, enable Firebase Installation API to your firebase key from 
[Firebase: 403 PERMISSION_DENIED (FirebaseError: Installations): Requests are blocked, after updating SDKs (FirebaseInstallationsService)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495985/firebase-403-permission-denied-firebaseerror-installations-requests-are-blo)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and in my case, so i run two commands "flutter clean" and then "flutter pub get" and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your date and time on emulator are correct. It fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions. Nothing worked. Ultimately I had to delete the Application from the Firebase project, re-create it and add the newly generated `google-services.json`.

While at it, I also changed the Firebase-flutter dependencies to

```
  firebase_core: ^1.5.0
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.5
```

And android dependencies to

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.1')
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

My issue had started after I added the SHA-1 code after setting up the application.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this on my Flutter app but none of the solutions I found online works. After a dozen hair-pulling hours, what works for me is to run it in release mode via.

```
flutter build apk
```

and install it via adb

```
adb install project/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace google-services.json file
2. Delete project in Firebase console & re-create again
3. Deleting Generated & Build files
4. Flutter clean

Non of above worked for me.

I had to change the application id & re-created firebase app again

Answer (score 0):

We also encountered the same issue, while checking the google-services.json file, we found two entries of same key "api_key" .. removing the duplicate entry got the project working.

(Maybe it was due to corrupted json file download from console, which might be solved if downloaded again, as mentioned in the previous answers)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just there was no internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Emulator has Internet access.
In my case it was "just" that: the Emulator had no Internet conection. I'm on a Mac M1.
How to solve? Was easy thanks to this guy https://medium.com/@daydreamer_/how-to-fix-android-emulator-wi-fi-connected-with-no-internet-c62fd4ed652d :

Android Emulator requires the Google DNS 8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4. Set it on your computer as DNS and off you go.