# Firebase Installations API - CreateInstallation Error (Android application)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform

Recently I've noticed on my Google Cloud Platform a 25%-30% erroneous traffic coming from CreateInstallation method of Firebase Installations API (error code 403) and 1% from GenerateAuthToken (code 400). Is that a normal situation? If not then what could possibly be a problem?

I really do appreciate any information regarding the issue, thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I'm not sure if this is related but I was able to reduce Firebase Firestore error rate by a slight margin (entry *Total Errors* in *Firebase Console/Cloud Firestore/Rules/Monitor rules*) by double checking of my *Security Rules* and adding conditional check `request.auth != null` before `request.auth.uid == uid`. Of course the main problem is still valid.

```
function isAuthorized(uid) { return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid; }
```

Comment: Same problem here but we haven't figured out a solution. Did you?

Comment: Haven't found a solution or even explanation for this phenomenon

Comment: Have you guys tried to investigate the issue as outlined in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58496014/2402281)? EDIT: Sorry, just saw that you already commented on that answer. :/