# Firebase: 403 Permission Denied (Firebase Dynamic Links)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm implementing **Firebase Dynamic Links** on iOS and bumped into a problem when method

```
let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(url) { (dynamicLink, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
            print(dynamicLink.url)
        }
      }
```

always return this error:

```
Error Domain=com.firebase.dynamicLinks Code=403 "(null)" UserInfo={code=403, message=Requests to this API firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com method google.firebase.dynamiclinks.v1.DynamicLinksService.GetIosReopenAttribution are blocked., status=PERMISSION_DENIED, details=(
        {
        "@type" = "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo";
        domain = "googleapis.com";
        metadata =         {
            consumer = "*********";
            service = "firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com";
        };
        reason = "API_KEY_SERVICE_BLOCKED";
    }
)}
```

Already have done manipulations with **Firebase Service** account and API's on **Google Cloud Platforms** — no effect.

Maybe somebody know what can be done in such situations?

Comment: This is specific to Firebase OAuth, but I imagine there is a key restriction that you can find in the dropdown particular to your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495985/firebase-403-permission-denied-firebaseerror-installations-requests-are-blo