# Google Analytics API Key restriction

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I'm trying to restrict the `Browser key (auto created by Firebase)` GCP API Key to the absolute minimum required to run my Firebase app. I'm getting this error:

`@firebase/analytics: Failed to fetch this Firebase app's measurement ID from the server. Falling back to the measurement ID G-VBVFV9NYDB provided in the "measurementId" field in the local Firebase config. [Analytics: Dynamic config fetch failed: [403] Requests to this API firebase.googleapis.com method google.firebase.service.v1alpha.DynamicConfigService.GetDynamicWebConfig are blocked. (analytics/config-fetch-failed).]`

Which API do I need to enable to resolve it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Also:


FirebaseError: Installations: Create Installation request failed with error "400 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument." (installations/request-failed).

Comment: tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495985/firebase-403-permission-denied-firebaseerror-installations-requests-are-blo?rq=2 didn't work.

Comment: @LeonardoBarbosa you need to allow Firebase Installations API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling `Firebase Management API` solved the problem.