Firebase In-App Messaging Not Displaying Campaigns - PERMISSION_DENIED Error
I'm implementing Firebase In-App Messaging in my Android app, but campaigns sent from the Firebase console are not displaying. Here is the issue I'm encountering, as seen in
Logcat:
Forcing fetch from service rather than cache. Test Device: false | App Fresh Install: true
Recoverable exception while reading cache: /data/user/0/package_name/files/fiam_impressions_store_file: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
Fetching campaigns from service.
Service fetch error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Requests to this API firebaseinappmessaging.googleapis.com method google.internal.firebase.inappmessaging.v1.sdkserving.InAppMessagingSdkServing.FetchEligibleCampaigns are blocked.

Attempted Solutions:

Enabled the In-App Messaging API from the Firebase console.

Rebuilt the project multiple times.


Dependency:
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:21.0.0")
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:22.0.0'

How can I resolve the PERMISSION_DENIED error and get Firebase In-App Messaging campaigns to display in my app?

Removing the API restrictions works for me (last comment): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881422/firebase-in-app-messaging-permission-denied

You have to add the firebase In-App Messaging permission to your Google Cloud API, you can add from the Google Cloud Console.
Try this Answer : Link
